# Getting different response in node.js with "same" request made in SOAP.ui

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, header

I have a SOAP request which needs to have an authorization header to be able to make the request.

I've been able to successfully make a request through SOAP.ui setting an header in the Header tab (not with the Header tag).

In node.js, I'm adding the header with addHttpHeader:

```
client.addHttpHeader('Authorization', httpHeader);
```

where httpHeader is a token.

When calling the api (through node), I'm getting an error

> 401: Unauthorized - Token oauth not authenticated

This response is the same as when I make the request (in SOAP.ui) without setting the header (in the header tab) or when I'm setting the header in the xml with:

```
<Header>
    <Authorization>value of my token </Authorization>
</Header>
```

When checking my request, the httpHeader is there:

```
httpHeaders: 
   { Authorization: 'some values' }
```

What could've been doing wrong to not being able to make the request through node but being able to make it with SOAP.ui?

Is there a way that I could check how the request is being sent in SOAP.ui so I can try to replicate it in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analizing closely how my request was, the httpHeader '**Authorization**' was indeed being sent but in the wrong *format*.
It should be something like

> 'Token XXXXXXX'

but because of the function **BasicAuthSecurity** that I was calling before adding the **httpHeader**, it was sending like

> 'Basic YYYY'

Removing the **BasicAuthSecurity** solved the problem.